# How can I determine what libraries I have available / how do I install boost?

Tags: c++, boost, installation

I am using MinGW from the command line and I want to derterime which boost libraries I have available...particularly I need to do some discrete graphs and threading...

When I try

```
include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

I get a no such file or directory.

So a better question might be how do I install boost to my C++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

You can get a tarball of the latest Boost release here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.47.0/

Untar/zip (depending on your platform), and you'll find a binary named 'bjam' or 'bjam.exe'.  Bjam is the Boost extension of the Perforce (J)ust (A)nother (M)ake build system.  If you run bjam from inside the directory that you just unpacked, then it should automagically configure the build and run it.  After that I think you type 'bjam install' (with the proper privs) and it puts the boost includes in the most likely place that your compile will look for them and the object code in the most likely place that your linker will look for them.  OR... bjam will produce an error message (which will hopefully be helpful) and halt.  The whole procedure is pretty brainless once you've done it once.  Things get complicated if you want to use MPI or some of the more advanced features of Boost.Serialize (not really, you just need zlib-devel and something else, I forget what).

HTH!

Comment: of course, if you're only going to use headers, then you can just copy the headers into your include path.  unfortunately, Boost.Thread requires some object code I think, so if you're going to use that, then you'll have to compile the Boost libs. You could compile them by hand, but bjam is the best way, since it's less likely to make a mistake.